# PHP if statement not working in preg_replace

Tags: php, if-statement, preg-replace, line

I have a simple PHP of statement but it keeps giving me 'Internal 500'.
Can anyone see what is wrong with this code?

(It works without the 'if')

```
$fullyfiltered = preg_replace('/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/', '<div class="chat-message ' if('$1'=="MichaelD"){'me'}else{'chat-midnightblue'}'"><div class="chat-contact"><img src="/assets/demo/avatar/tswan.png" alt=""></div><div id="chat-text" class="chat-text">$1: ', $nearlyfiltered);
```

**EDIT - Full script:**

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('chat-text').innerHTML = '';
    <?php
    $fh = fopen('chat.txt','r');
    while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
    //echo "<p>" . $line . "</p>";
    $filtered = str_replace("'", "\\'", $line);
    $almostfiltered = str_replace("<span></span>\n", "", $filtered);
    $nearlyfiltered = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $almostfiltered));
    $fullyfiltered = preg_replace('/<span>(.*?)<\/span>/', '<div class="chat-message ' if('$one'=="MichaelD"){'me'}else{'chat-midnightblue'}'"><div class="chat-contact"><img src="/assets/demo/avatar/tswan.png" alt=""></div><div id="chat-text" class="chat-text">$1: ', $nearlyfiltered);
    if(!empty($fullyfiltered)){
        $endingp = "</div></div>';"; 
    } else {
        $endingp = "';";
    }
    echo "document.getElementById('chat-text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('chat-text').innerHTML + '" . $fullyfiltered . $endingp;
    }
    fclose($fh);
    ?>      
    },5000);
</script>
```

Comment: $1 isn't a variable. Try $one instead.(you cannot use numbers for php variables)

Comment: still errors even if I change that

Answer (score 1):

callback must be a function, not just random script parts. Please read the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Comment: can you give me an example using my script please?

Comment: sorry, im not too great with regex so I cant give you an exact example, simply a suggestion. You can find examples on PHP manual page, but working them in to your code is actually a part of being a developer, so first try out the suggestion and then ask for help if you have trouble.